# How to test Apple Universal Links in development?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I am working on apple universal links, but not able to find a way to test in development mode, as I installed app from Xcode debug mode and then open website, which still show view, not open on top app banner. Any help?

Comment: Can you describe in more detail the steps you have taken to enable universal links for your app? It would also be helpful if you could relate those steps to the steps in the documentation at https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

Comment: I followed exact same steps described in the link. When I open app link it shows view and open at top popup only when app installed from app store. But not deteching app when installed by xcode. If I install app via Xcode, it still show view, not open.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like when you added the Associated Domains Capability - you added it to "Release" but not "Debug".

You'll have to add your Associated Domain to"Debug".

In Xcode when you add and configure your Associated Domain, make sure you also do this on the "Debug" "Tab":

[image: "Debug" "Tab"]

Hope this helps someone!